# PyQt5 Filtered Dataframe

Tags: python, model, pyqt5, qtableview

thanks for taking the time to help me. I have an example that is really close to what I want, but I am unable to make it do an exact match filter. In the example below, if you type in "A" into the line edit you will get multiple hits. I want the user to have to have "Apple" to file as whole string match.  The issue in my real code is I have CM and CMI and I would want the filter to only show one.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()

# standard item model
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 3)
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'DATE', 'VALUE'])
for row, text in enumerate(['Cell', 'Fish', 'Apple', 'Ananas', 'Mango']):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
    model.setItem(row, 2, item)

# filter proxy model
filter_proxy_model = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(2) # third column

# line edit for filtering
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(window)
line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
line_edit.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)
layout.addWidget(line_edit)

# table view
table = QtGui.QTableView()
table.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
layout.addWidget(table)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if only the exact word match, so that if the user starts to type "Apple" the table will be empty until it ends to type it?

Comment: Exact match would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an exact match, you can use the regexp delimitators to ensure that only the exact string is compared:

```
def fullFilter(text):
    filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp('^{}$'.format(text))

line_edit.textChanged.connect(fullFilter)
# to ignore case sensitivity (matching "apple", "aPpLe", etc.):
filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(False)
```

The `^` symbol indicates that the match will have to be at the *beginning* of the string, while the `$` ensures that match will also have to be at the *end* of it.